# Virtuemart 3.4 - products on manufacturer page

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, virtuemart, joomla3.8, joomla-4.x

Virtuemart 3.4.2, joomla 3.8
i try copy code from category template, but cant fix this errors: 
at /my_template/**html/com_virtuemart/manufacturer/details.php**

**NOW I HAVE Two ERRORS**:

**Call to a member function getLimitBox() on null**

```
<div class="display-number"><?php echo 'по';?><?php echo $this->vmPagination->getLimitBox ($this->category->limit_list_step); ?></div>
```

**Call to a member function getPagesLinks() on null**

```
<?php echo $this->vmPagination->getPagesLinks (); ?>
```

Why this code from category not work in manufacturer template ? Please help , need worked code..

You can try copy template from category  to manufacturer folder and see this errors ..

Answer (score 0):

It's not working, because Joomla is not working this way. You cannot just copy a part of code from one template to another template. It would be very bad if Joomla (or any other CMS framework) worked that way nowadays.

**In your particular case:**

```
$this->vmPagination->getLimitBox ($this->category->limit_list_step)
```

and this part:

```
$this->vmPagination->getPagesLinks ();
```

are not defined in **view.html.php** file in the **views/manufaturer** folder and that is why it is not working.

You most probably need a Joomla developer, who understands the whole Joomla structure, to make this kind of pages work the way you would like to. Otherwise, I am sorry to say this, but I am a bit afraid that you will crash your site soon.